# ¿Que retorna @media (orientation:landscape) en pc?

Tags: css3, mediaqueries

Estoy intentando generar reglas para los casos donde *"orientation"* no esta disponible, como navegador sobre pc, pero no consigo que esta regla funcione,

Quiero que se contemplen los tres casos, *"orientation:portrait",* *"orientation:landscape"* y *"orientation:undefined"??*

intente con una regla como esta, pero sin resultados.

```
@media(min-width: 1px) and not ((orientation:portrait) , (orientation:landscape)) {}
```

Comment: En navegador pc tambien esta disponible, no solo hay monitores para pc que se pueden poner en vertical (como el mio) sino que la ventana del navegador (que es lo que cuenta) puede ser mas alta que ancha, independientemente del monitor

Comment: Cuando consultas con javascrip, el modo en escritorio, te retorna undefined

Comment: Perdon, creia que te referias exclusivamente a css, pero no entiendo, ¿por que no haces simplemente algo como  `if ( window.innerWidth>window.innerHeight)`? ¿puedes poner el codigo completo que estas usando?

Comment: claro, como no me estaba funcionando las querys, decidí preguntar que valor arrojaba con javascript, y ahi me retorno undefined; Estudiando un poco mas el asunto di con la respuesta, (orientation:portrait)= false si alto<ancho sino si alto=ancho o alto>ancho retorna true; lo mismo, pero al revés, en caso de landscape;
Sabiendo esto yo quería hacer reglas para saber si estoy en una pc o en otro dispositivo, cosa que no pude hacer con esa media query

Answer (score 0):

La media query (orientation:landscape/portrait) solo informa si es mas ancho que largo, o iguales(landscape), o si es mas largo que ancho(portrait)